# Deploying cloud function using terraform fails - "Invalid function service account requested"

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I want to deploy a Google Cloud Function and I wish to do so using terraform. I also wish to create a service account to act as a non-default service account for running that function as explained at [Function Identity > Per-function identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#per-function_identity). The ID of that service account is `dataflowdemo`.

I have created a service account that I wish to use for running my deployments (not the same as the service account mentioned in the previous paragraph), the ID of that service account is `deployer`:

```sh
export PROJECT=myproject
gcloud iam service-accounts create --project $PROJECT deployer
```

I downloaded a key file that I can reference in '$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS' as instructed at [Terraform Google Provider > Adding credentials](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#adding-credentials):

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$(pwd)/deployer.json
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create \
   --project $PROJECT \
   --iam-account deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

and have granted it the necessary permissions

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --member="serviceAccount:deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/storage.admin"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --member="serviceAccount:deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/cloudfunctions.admin"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --member="serviceAccount:deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT --member="serviceAccount:deployer@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/iam.roleAdmin"
```

The terraform code is fairly simple, it creates the `dataflowdemo` service account and specifies that service account as the non-default service account for a cloud function. The code is available at https://github.com/jamiekt/dataflowdemo/tree/6775ff7fd395320705a82ecb16f3fb054993ed57.

I run the terraform deployment like so:

```sh
terraform init && terraform apply --auto-approve
```

and it subsequently fails with:

> Error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid function service account requested: serviceAccount:dataflowdemo@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation., badRequest

I visited the link given in the error message which states:

> However, to use a non-default runtime service account, the deployer must have the iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission on that non-default account. **A user who creates a non-default runtime service account is automatically granted this permission**

The function deployer (i.e. the `deployer` service account) is the same account that created the function hence I am very confused why this is failing.

Please can someone tell me where I am going wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `functions.tf` file, you defined your service account like this

```
service_account_email = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.sa.email}"
```

Remove the `serviceAccount:` prefix

```
service_account_email = "${google_service_account.sa.email}"
```

Comment: thank you, that solved it. I also had to grant the deployment account roles/iam.serviceAccountUser. See commit https://github.com/jamiekt/dataflowdemo/commit/d35a3b92b0b1cd4d6caf999f8308717e3f067077 for details